# Select the 'no' on a separate sheet

Tags: excel

I want to Select the 'no' on a separate sheet with `vlookup`, but I can not get it to work.

This is the example on the first sheet:

```
1 Yes  Coffee
2 No   Tea
3 No   Milk
4 Yes  Water
5 Yes  Juice
```

On the next sheet it should show the following:

```
1 Tea
2 Milk
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I can't figure out what you're asking for from your question. What do you mean by "select the 'no'"? Could you provide an example or a screen shot? Could you describe what you have done that hasn't worked?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that Vlookup will be able to do what you want.  Since you'd be looking up "No", in a range with multiple "No"s, vLookup will return the same value over and over.  There's likely a solution with an equation, but I'm not that great with those, so here's a VBA solution.

Note: I assume that "Yes" and "No" are in Column A, and the drink type is in column B, similar to:

```
   A       B
1 Yes     Milk
2 No      Water
3 No      Tea
4 Yes     Juice
```

Code:

```
Sub Move_NO_Rows()
Dim rawWS As Worksheet, noWS As Worksheet
Dim yesNoRange As Range, cel As Range
Dim lastRow As Integer, noLastRow As Integer
Dim yesOrNo As String

yesOrNo = "No" 'If you want to search for the "Yes" rows instead, just change this variable

Set rawWS = ActiveSheet
Set noWS = Sheets.Add
noWS.Name = "No Types"

'Since we added a new sheet, the starting row for your "No" rows is 1
noLastRow = 1

With rawWS
    lastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Set yesNoRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 1))
    For Each cel In yesNoRange
        If cel.Value = yesOrNo Then
            noWS.Range(noWS.Cells(noLastRow, 1), noWS.Cells(noLastRow, 2)).Value = .Range(.Cells(cel.Row, 1), .Cells(cel.Row, 2)).Value
            noLastRow = noLastRow + 1
        End If
    Next cel
End With

End Sub
```

Are the numbers you give in your example actually in the data, or is that the row?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-VBA solution. Note that this uses Array Formulas, which must be confirmed by pressing CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER each time the cell is modified, instead of just ENTER. Put your "yes" / "no" column from A1:A6, and your drink column from B1:B6. Put a column from D1:D6 which just counts from 1 to 6.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$6,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$6="no",ROW($A$1:$A$6),""),D1)),"")
```

After pressing CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER, copy down to the rows below. This works by looking at each possible hit in column A. Where column A = "no" in that row, it gives the row number to the SMALL function. SMALL takes an array of numbers, and spits out the one that is the nth smallest. So SMALL(LIST,2) gives the 2nd smallest item in the list. You then can give this row number to the Index function, which takes column B, and spits out the value in the given row.

I don't recommend you use this without understanding it; I don't recommend you use it at all if you are not familiar with Array functions.